# Replace string in all rows except the first with Python

Tags: python

I have the following code to replace all '.' with ',':

```
text = open("test_old.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]).replace(".", ",")
x = open("test_new.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

It also removes full stops from the first row. Is there any way not to change the first row?

test_old.csv looks like this:

```
"P.A";"P.B"
"3.4";"6.4"
"2.3";"9.5"
```

test_new.csv should look like this:

```
"P.A";"P.B"
"3,4";"6,4"
"2,3";"9,5"
```

Comment: I would consider using [pythons builtin `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). It has functionality for headers already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('test_old.csv') as text, open('test_new.csv', 'w') as out:
   out.write(next(text))
   for row in text:
      out.write(row.replace('.', ','))
```

This avoids expensive joins and array appends.

Comment: `Next` will not remove the first line from text? Won't you print the header twice?

Comment: `rest = ''.join([i for i in text[1:]).replace('.', ',')`

Comment: @leopardxpreload nope it does not. you can test it.

Comment: My appologies @theEpsilon - You are right and thats a good bit of knowledge

Answer (score 4):

Append the first unchanged to the rest changed?

```py
text = text[0] + ''.join([i for i in text[1:]]).replace(".", ",")
```

Comment: This has the disadvantage of loading a (potentially) huge file into memory all at once, as well as doing expensive array appending

Answer (score 0):

```
header = True
with open("test_old.csv", "r") as fin, open("test_new.csv", "w") as fout:
    for line in fin:
      if not header:
        fout.write(line.replace('.', ','))
      else:
        fout.write(line)
        header = False
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.